# How to integrate custom fields with the Rules module?

Tags: 7, entities, rules

I want to integrate the D7 custom field module I wrote with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module so that values can be copied from my custom field to other fields and vice versa.

So far I got this function that is defined as the property_callback in the _field_info function:

```
function b2share_field_property_callback(&$info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type) {
  $property = &$info[$entity_type]['bundles'][$instance['bundle']]['properties'][$field['field_name']];

  $property['getter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get';
  $property['setter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set';


  $property['property info'] = array(
    'doi' => array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => t('DOI'),
      'description' => t('Subfield of Field "'.$field['field_name'].'".'),
      'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
      'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',

     ),
    'pid' => array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => t('PID'),
      'description' => t('Subfield of Field "'.$field['field_name'].'".'),
      'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
      'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',

  ),
);
unset($property['query callback']);
}
```

The subfields of my field show up in the rules config menu, but when I try to do something with them their values can't be accessed. 
EDIT: Meaning that my field and its subfields have values stored. When viewing a node you can see them, when you edit the node you can see and change them. They are displayed in a view, but when I try to copy them using a rule an empty string will be copied to another field. At the same time no values can be set for my custom field using rules.

This is my rule for testing. It is supposed to add some string to the field, but doesn't have any effect.

```
  { "rules_edit_b2share_link" : {
    "LABEL" : "Edit B2Share Link",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : {
      "node_insert--data_set" : { "bundle" : "data_set" },
      "node_update--data_set" : { "bundle" : "data_set" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-b2share:doi" ], "value" : "44444" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the second rule, that's not working either. It ends up copying an empty string to the "abstract" field.

```
  { "rules_copy_b2share_link_to_another_field" : {
    "LABEL" : "Copy B2Share Link to another field",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--data_set" : { "bundle" : "data_set" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "node:field-abstract:value" ],
          "value" : [ "node:field-b2share:doi" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I just edited the question. The field consists of two subfields, both of them filled with text values, but rules fails to copy them to another text fields and also fails to replace the subfield values with another string value.

Comment: OK, your updated question makes it much more clear (I trust you noticed I fixed the formatting of your exported rules). It might be worth trying to add an extra rules action "save entity" (eventually also trying with "Force saving immediately)". If it helps I might convert this to a real answer. Disclosure: consider this rather as something "worth trying" (not more then that). PS: also worth it: temporary add a "display drupal msg" a first Rules Action, to be SURE the Rules Conditions are true (if not then you're close to pinpointing your isue).

Comment: The rule is being triggered as it displays the test message. I tried to add a "save entity" rule, but my custom field wasn't in the list. Why could that be?

Comment: OK, good to know that the test msg displayed (debugging = taking away all possible reasons why it may not work). However, I find it strange that your list seems incomplete. But that rings a new bell ... here is another "worth trying" (same disclosure): add a 1st Rules Action to "Fetch an entity by id" ... Hoping/assuing you have something you can use to specify as ID. And remove (at least for now) that "Save entity".